# CreateProcessAsUser issue on Windows

Tags: winapi, access-token, impersonation

I'm trying to get user token via LogonUser() WinAPI call and execute process via that user on windows by CreateProcessAsUser () call. The problem is that I get 1314 'A required privilege is not held by the client' error. I'm currently logged in via 'Pearl' and as you see I'm using my own credentials there. This used is in Administrators group, I also checked the Local Security Policy and this user has all necessary permissions (Act as part of operating system, Create token object and Log on as batch job. My code is:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <userenv.h>

int enable_priv(HANDLE hToken, const char* name)
{
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;

  memset(&tp, 0, sizeof(tp));

  if (LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, name, &tp.Privileges[0].Luid) == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %ld\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
  }

  tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
  tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

  if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), NULL, 0) == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %ld.\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  HANDLE hToken1   = NULL;
  HANDLE dup = NULL;

  STARTUPINFO si = {0};

  PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {0};

  si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);

  DWORD flags =  CREATE_NO_WINDOW;

  fprintf(stderr, "testlog starting...\n");

  if (OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY |     TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken1) == 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "token failed code '%lu'.\n", GetLastError());

    return -1;
  }

  enable_priv(hToken1, SE_TCB_NAME);
  enable_priv(hToken1, SE_ASSIGNPRIMARYTOKEN_NAME);
  enable_priv(hToken1, SE_INCREASE_QUOTA_NAME);

  if (LogonUser("Pearl", NULL, "pass",
                    LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken1) == 0)
  {

    fprintf(stderr, " Interactive logon failed.\n");

    return 0;
  }

  if (DuplicateTokenEx(hToken1, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityDelegation,
                       TokenPrimary, &dup) == 0)
  {

    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR is '%lu'.\n",  GetLastError());

    return 0;
  }


  fprintf(stderr, "testlog executing...\n");

  fflush(stderr);
  fflush(stdout);

  if (CreateProcessAsUser(dup, NULL, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\folder1\\tazo.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE,
                           flags, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi) == 0)
 {
    fprintf(stderr, "testlog Error is '%lu'\n", GetLastError());
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: The most likely cause is that the user running the program doesn't have both of the necessary privileges.  (You don't mention checking "Replace a process-level token"?  Also note that the program must be run elevated.)  As it happens, AdjustTokenPrivileges is one of the rare functions where the last error code is set even if the call reports success.  Check the last error code to see whether all the privileges you're attempting to enable were actually available.  (And once you've changed the code to do that, please update the code in the question to the new version.)

Comment: Thank you very much @HarryJohnston, It worked, now application is started but for some reason it cannot open files, I can open some files when logging in via "Pearl", but if I launch process with that user's token, it cannot open them. any idea? I used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379608(v=vs.85).aspx this example

Comment: I mean if I launch tazo.exe by hand it works fine, but launching in above-described way fails to access some files

Comment: The child process won't have elevated privileges, e.g., won't be a member of Administrators.  If you need an elevated token, use `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` rather than `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE`.

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Could you please answer this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408556/winapi-impersonate-client-pipe-and-createprocess