# Trouble setting ownership when impersonating

Tags: winapi, permissions, impersonation

Here is my code:

```
logonSuccess = LogonUserW(userPartW, domainPartW, pwdW,
                            LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH,
                                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &token);

Int result1 = SetNamedSecurityInfo("C:\\file.crt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, yveri, NULL, NULL, NULL);

fprintf(stderr, "result -> %d.\n", result1); //which gives me 0

if (ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(token) == FALSE)
{
  printf("Imperesonating failed.\n");
  return -1;
}

Int result2 = SetNamedSecurityInfo("C:\\Users\\nx\\.nx\\config\\authorized.crt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, yveri, NULL, NULL, NULL);

fprintf(stderr, "result -> %d.\n", result2); //which gives me 5
```

The first call to SetNamedSecurityInfo works, but the second call (once impersonation is in place) returns error code 5.

Comment: Why are you using `CreateFile()` on the server side? You should be using `ConnectNamePipe()` instead.  A named pipe client uses `CreateFile()` to connect to a named pipe.  A named pipe server uses `CreateNamedPipe()` to open the pipe, and then `ConnectNamedPipe()` to accept clients on the pipe. If you use `CreateFile()` on the server side, it is going to connect to its own pipe and then impersonate itself.

Comment: Thanks for response @RemyLebeau I typed my code incorrectly here, please check the edited code

Comment: What rights specifically doesn't the process you create have?

Comment: The process can't set ownerership of specific file

Comment: Basically the problem Is in `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`  before this function I do this `Int result1 = SetNamedSecurityInfo("C:\\Users\\nx\\.nx\\config\\authorized.crt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
                                          OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, yveri, NULL,
                                            NULL, NULL);   fprintf(stderr, "result -> %d.\n", result1);` which gives me 0, but after `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` I do the same but it gives me '5'. (Client application I've edited code above)

Comment: **Now** you're talking about the named pipe client. Your question states that the problem is with the program that is being run by the named pipe server. Please decide what is the problem. My psychic debugging powers (TM Raymond Chen) tell me that the user whose username is stored in `userPartW` simply doesn't have permissions to set the owner of the file `C:\Users\nx\.nx\config\authorized.crt` and you haven't enabled the `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` privilege after beginning impersonation. Why should it work?

Comment: Clearly nothing to do with named pipes or CreateProcessAsUser.  So discard all of that stuff and just focus on the calls to SetNamedSecurityInfo.  Please provide an [MCVE], showing in particular how you're creating `yveri`.  You should also be attempting to change the same file in both cases, otherwise you're comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: One guess: `yveri` contains the SID for the current user, so when you're running as the current user the change is permitted, but when you're running as someone else it isn't.  (You can't give someone else ownership of a file unless you've enabled restore privilege.)  The only situation in which the code as shown can work is if `yveri` contains the SID for the local `Administrators` group.  (The problem might also be that you've enabled one or more priivleges for the main process token, and forgotten to do the same thing for the impersonation token.)

Comment: Yes, I enabled privileges to that toke and it worked :) thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on what we figured out in the comments:

When you call any of the impersonation functions (`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`, `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`, `RpcImpersonateClient`, etc.) you're basically calling `SetThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), __GetInterestingToken())` (where `GetInterestingToken()` is a placeholder for getting the relevant token for each function).

When you perform any action that makes a security check against the **current** security context<sup>1</sup> it makes the check against the current thread's token - **whatever it is** - if it exists. Otherwise it makes the check against the process token.

There's no "inheritance" of any sort from the process's security context to the thread's when the thread has a token attached to it. You either get the process's security context (all of it and nothing else) or a specific security context for the thread (and nothing else!).

That's actually the whole point behind impersonation, it's *raison d'etre*<sup>2</sup>.

Any success you had in doing anything before impersonation is completely irrelevant to your ability to perform the same action after impersonation<sup>3</sup>. Since you haven't enabled the privileges that allow you to change kernel objects' owner (`SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` to make yourself the owner, and as Harry Johnston correctly said - `SeRestorePrivilege` to set someone else to be the owner) your attempt to change it is denied.

Enable the necessary privilege (assuming the token has it) to be able to change the owner.

---

<sup>1</sup> In contrast to code that intentionally makes the check against another security context, such as when passing `OpenAsSelf = TRUE` to `OpenThreadToken`.

<sup>2</sup> The classic example given when explaining client impersonation is a file server running as `LOCAL_SYSTEM` impersonation the client during request servicing to make sure it doesn't accidently (or intentionally...) access files the client isn't allowed to access. If during impersonation any abilities (permissions or privileges) "leaked" to the impersonating thread that would pretty much defeat the purpose of impersonating the client.

<sup>3</sup> Except in the special case of `ImpersonateSelf`, where obviously you should be able to do anything you could have done before impersonation.